# Searching for a novel with a nature-based AI

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a novel that has a computer (AI) made of earth and plants.

- It takes place on Earth.
- I recall the avatar described as seeming to walk in dirt, like Pigpen (from Peanuts).

Comment: I know it is not "The Stone God Awakens."  I read that, as well as the book I am searching for. I read a lot, and sometimes the details about a particular book get confused with others.  I am only posting what I am certain of.  I am certain it takes place in the near future. The computer is built of natural elements, dirt, plants and insects.  The avatar manifests as seeming to walk in a dust cloud.  The protagonist encounters it at some point during a public gathering.  Later the protagonist finds it.

Answer (score 2):

Is is Philip J.(*lol*) Farmer's "[The Stone God Awakens](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1526312.The_Stone_God_Awakens)"?

Per [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0441786545);

> Ulysses Singing Bear is a 20th century scientist that becomes frozen
>   in an "instant of time" as a result of a scientific experiment that
>   goes very wrong. Fast-forward a million years and "somehow" the stone
>   god, as Ulysses has been referred too down through the eons, becomes
>   unfrozen. He finds warring races of intelligent, but technologically
>   primitive beings evolved from cats, raccoons, monkeys, bats, elephants
>   etc, dominating this future. Ulysses pulls off a masterful deception
>   and insures his survival by convincing the natives that his
>   reinvention of military weapons: bows and arrows and gunpowder are
>   manifestations of his "god-like" powers. Eventually he sets out on a
>   journey to find other humans. In order to reach the coast, where he
>   surmised men would dwell, he must transverse The Tree. This massive
>   plant is several miles high, spreads out hundreds of miles and is
>   inhabited by a host of deadly plants, animals and warring clans.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this might be the answer?

Comment: Nothing in the Goodreads description has any mentioned similarity to the work in question.

Comment: Well: 1. It takes place on future Earth. 2. Main antogonist is overgrown conscious tree-computer (AI made of earth and plants) 3. Protagonist walks in dirt. Alot. Link to Goodreaders was taken by random, just to show what book did I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly Slant by [Greg Bear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Bear)?

The antagonist AI is notable by being based on environmental networks ([see here](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/172742.Slant)).